# Good performance when predicting future game states

Tags: java, performance, beginner, game, tree

This question is about [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34851/slime-the-territory-war/34910#34910) to [this king-of-the-hill challenge on Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34851/slime-the-territory-war). In short, the purpose of the challenge is to code a slime that, trough various possible moves gains control over an 8x8 play area against 3 other slimes. The slimes get their turn one after another.

My idea was to go trough all possible moves for the next few rounds, put a score on each possible outcome and then estimating which possible move would be the best. I decided I should at least look as far as after my own next move, but as there are somewhere around 100 possible moves each turn, this quickly gets too slow. I now randomly skip a certain percentage of possible moves, based on a guess of how many moves there are:

```
double skip = (us*2.5/(us*2.5 + 1))/4 + 0.735;
```

Where `us` is an integer that indicates how many of the currently active player are on the board. On the first turn, I don't skip any moves and on the second I multiply the skip ratio by itself, since the base of the tree is more important to me. As you can see, I am skipping a lot of branches.

**TL; DR: I'm doing some tree searches on the board states of a game, I need to get the performance up.**

How can I improve my code **to run faster** so I don't need to skip so many branches?  Seeing as I'm not a very experienced programmer at all and Java is very new to me, I'm sure the performance can be orders of magnitude better.

**A few things I can think of that could use improving:**

- I have a fixed size array to store boardstates that have already been over (since some moves have the same outcome) the way I handle this might be slowing me down.
- Am I returning values that don't need returning since they are passed as a reference?
- Should I be storing the boardstates more efficiently?
- My choice of language might not be the best.
- Though probably not directly related to performance, the main loop in my `getBestMove` method is a mess.

Any other feedback on my code is of course also welcomed, but performance goes first in this case.

Here's my full code:

```
import java.awt.Point;  

public class ShallowBlue {
    private static final int MAX_ROUNDS = 5, PLAYERS = 4;
    static int me = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args[0] == null) {
                return;
        }

    me = Integer.parseInt(args[0].split(",", 2)[0]);
    String board = args[0].split(",", 2)[1];

    System.out.println(getBestMove(board, me, MAX_ROUNDS - 1));
}

private static String getBestMove(String board, int player, int rounds) {
    String [] boards = new String[24];
    int checkedBoards = 1;
    char playerChar = Integer.toString(player).charAt(0);
    String tempMove = getMove(0, 0, 0, 0);
    String tempBoard = calculateMove(board, tempMove); 
    boards[0] = tempBoard;
    String bestMove = tempMove;
    double us = numberOfUs(board, playerChar); 
    double skip = (us*2.5/(us*2.5 + 1))/4 + 0.735;
    if (rounds == MAX_ROUNDS - 2) {
        skip = skip*skip;
    }

    float bestScore, worstScore, averageScore, tempScore;
    int scores;

    if (rounds == 0) {
        tempScore = calculateScore(tempBoard, MAX_ROUNDS - rounds - 1);
    } else {
        tempScore = getScore(getBestMove(tempBoard, player%PLAYERS + 1, rounds - 1));
    }

    scores = 1;
    bestScore = tempScore;
    worstScore = tempScore;
    averageScore = tempScore;

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            if (getCharAt(board, x, y) == playerChar) {
                Point[] possibleMergers = getNeighboringMatches(board, new Point(x, y), playerChar);
                if (possibleMergers[0] != null) {
                    tempMove = getMove(possibleMergers[0].x, possibleMergers[0].y, x, y); 
                    tempBoard = calculateMove(board, tempMove);
                    if (addIfUnique(boards, tempBoard, checkedBoards)) {
                        checkedBoards++;
                        if ((rounds != MAX_ROUNDS - 1) && (rounds == 0 || Math.random() < skip)) {
                            tempScore = calculateScore(tempBoard, MAX_ROUNDS - rounds - 1);
                        } else {
                            tempScore = getScore(getBestMove(tempBoard, player%PLAYERS + 1, rounds - 1));
                        }

                        if (tempScore > bestScore) {
                            bestMove = tempMove;
                        }
                        bestScore = Math.max(tempScore, bestScore);
                        worstScore = Math.min(tempScore, worstScore);

                        scores++;
                        averageScore = (averageScore*(scores - 1) + tempScore)/scores;
                    }
                }
            } else if (getCharAt(board, x, y) == '.') {
                Point[] possibleSpreaders = getNeighboringMatches(board, new Point(x, y), playerChar);
                int i = 0;
                while (i < possibleSpreaders.length && possibleSpreaders[i] != null) {
                    tempMove = getMove(possibleSpreaders[i].x, possibleSpreaders[i].y, x, y); 
                    tempBoard = calculateMove(board, tempMove);
                    if ((rounds != MAX_ROUNDS - 1) && (rounds == 0 || Math.random() < skip)) {
                        tempScore = calculateScore(tempBoard, MAX_ROUNDS - rounds - 1);
                    } else {
                        tempScore = getScore(getBestMove(tempBoard, player%PLAYERS + 1, rounds - 1));
                    }

                    if (tempScore > bestScore) {
                        bestMove = tempMove;
                    }
                    bestScore = Math.max(tempScore, bestScore);
                    worstScore = Math.min(tempScore, worstScore);

                    scores++;
                    averageScore = (averageScore*(scores - 1) + tempScore)/scores;

                    i++;
                }
                Point[] possibleJumpers = getNextNeighboringMatches(board, new Point(x, y), playerChar);
                i = 0;
                while (i < possibleJumpers.length && possibleJumpers[i] != null) {
                    tempMove = getMove(possibleJumpers[i].x, possibleJumpers[i].y, x, y); 
                    tempBoard = calculateMove(board, tempMove);
                    if ((rounds != MAX_ROUNDS - 1) && (rounds == 0 || Math.random() < skip)) {
                        tempScore = calculateScore(tempBoard, MAX_ROUNDS - rounds - 1);
                    } else {
                        tempScore = getScore(getBestMove(tempBoard, player%PLAYERS + 1, rounds - 1));
                    }

                    if (tempScore > bestScore) {
                        bestMove = tempMove;
                    }
                    bestScore = Math.max(tempScore, bestScore);
                    worstScore = Math.min(tempScore, worstScore);

                    scores++;
                    averageScore = (averageScore*(scores - 1) + tempScore)/scores;

                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (rounds == MAX_ROUNDS - 1) {
        return (bestMove);
    } else {
        return getScoreString(bestScore, worstScore, averageScore);
    }
}

private static int numberOfUs(String board, char playerChar) {
    int us = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length(); i++ ) {
         if (board.charAt(i) == playerChar) {
            us++;
        }
    }

    return us;
}

private static float calculateScore(String board, int roundsPassed) {
    int empties = 0;
    int us = 0;
    int enemy1 = 0;
    int enemy2 = 0;
    int enemy3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length(); i++ ) {
        if (board.charAt(i) == '.') {
            empties++;
        } else if (board.charAt(i) == Integer.toString(me).charAt(0)) {
            us++;
        } else if (board.charAt(i) == Integer.toString(me%PLAYERS + 1).charAt(0)) {
            enemy1++;
        } else if (board.charAt(i) == Integer.toString(me%PLAYERS + 2).charAt(0)) {
            enemy2++;
        } else if (board.charAt(i) == Integer.toString(me%PLAYERS + 3).charAt(0)) {
            enemy3++;
        }
    }

    if (us != 0) {
        us += roundsPassed;
    }

    if (enemy1 != 0) { 
        enemy1 = enemy1 + (roundsPassed + 3)%PLAYERS;
    }

    if (enemy2 != 0) { 
        enemy2 = enemy2 + (roundsPassed + 2)%PLAYERS;
    }

    if (enemy3 != 0) { 
        enemy3 = enemy3 + (roundsPassed + 1)%PLAYERS;
    }

    return us*(empties + 1)/(Math.max(Math.max(enemy1, enemy2), enemy3) + 1);
}

private static float getScore(String scoreString) {
    float bestScore, worstScore, averageScore;
    String[] scores = new String[3];

    scores = scoreString.split(",");
    bestScore = Float.parseFloat(scores[0]);
    worstScore = Float.parseFloat(scores[1]);
    averageScore = Float.parseFloat(scores[2]);


    return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(bestScore*averageScore*worstScore*worstScore));
}

private static String getScoreString(float bestScore, float worstScore, float averageScore) {
    return Float.toString(bestScore) + ',' + Float.toString(worstScore) + ',' + Float.toString(averageScore);
}

private static boolean addIfUnique(String[] boards, String board, int checkedBoards) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < boards.length && boards[i] != null) {
        if (boards[i].equals(board)) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (i < boards.length) {
        boards[i] = board;
    } else {
        boards[checkedBoards%boards.length] = board;
    }

    return true;
}

private static String calculateMove(String board, String move) {
    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(move.charAt(0)));
    int y1 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(move.charAt(2)));
    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(move.charAt(4)));
    int y2 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(move.charAt(6)));

    if ((Math.abs(y1 - y2) == 2 || Math.abs(x1 - x2) == 2) 
            &&  getCharAt(board, x2, y2) == '.') {
        Point[] enemies = new Point[8];

        enemies = getNeighboringEnemies(board, new Point(x1, y1), Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(getCharAt(board, x1, y1))));

        board = replace(board, enemies, getCharAt(board, x1, y1));
        Point[] middle = {new Point(x1, y1)};
        board = replace(board, middle, '.');
    }

    if ((Math.abs(y1 - y2) == 1 || Math.abs(x1 - x2) == 1)) { 
        if (getCharAt(board, x2, y2) == '.' || getCharAt(board, x1, y1) == getCharAt(board, x2, y2)) {
            boolean merge = true;
            if (getCharAt(board, x2, y2) == '.') {
                merge = false;
            }

            Point[] spaces = new Point[8];
            spaces = getNeighboringMatches(board, new Point(x1, y1), '.');
            board = replace(board, spaces, getCharAt(board, x1, y1));

            if (merge) {
                Point[] source = {new Point(x1, y1)};
                board = replace(board, source, '.');
            }
        }
    }

    return board;
}

private static String replace(String board, Point[] targets, char source) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < targets.length && targets[i] != null) {
        if (targets[i].x == 7 && targets[i].y == 7) {
            board = board.substring(0, getIndexAt(targets[i].x, targets[i].y)) + source;
        } else if (targets[i].x == 0 && targets[i].y == 0) {
            board = source + board.substring(getIndexAt(targets[i].x, targets[i].y) + 1);
        } else {
            board = board.substring(0, getIndexAt(targets[i].x, targets[i].y)) + source + board.substring(getIndexAt(targets[i].x, targets[i].y) + 1);
        }
        i++;
    }

    return board;
}

private static Point[] getNeighboringMatches(String board, Point coord, char match) {
    Point[] matches = new Point[8];

    int i = 0;
    for (int x = coord.x - 1; x <= coord.x + 1; x++) {
        for (int y = coord.y - 1; y <= coord.y + 1; y++) {
            if ((y != coord.y || x != coord.x ) && getCharAt(board, x, y) == match){
                matches[i] = new Point(x, y);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

private static Point[] getNeighboringEnemies(String board, Point coord, int player) {
    Point[] enemies = new Point[8];

    for (int i = 1; i <= PLAYERS; i++){
        enemies = mergeArr(enemies, getNeighboringMatches(board, coord, Integer.toString((player + i - 1)%PLAYERS + 1).charAt(0)));
    }

    return enemies;
}

private static Point[] getNextNeighboringMatches(String board, Point coord, char match) {
    Point[] matches = new Point[16];

    int i = 0;
    for (int x = coord.x - 2; x <= coord.x + 2; x++) {
        for (int y = coord.y - 2; y <= coord.y + 2; y++) {
            if ((Math.abs(y - coord.y) == 2 || Math.abs(x - coord.x) == 2) && getCharAt(board, x, y) == match){
                matches[i] = new Point(x, y);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

private static char getCharAt(String board, int x, int y) {

    if (x >= 0 && x < 8 && y >= 0 && y < 8) {
        return board.charAt(9*x + y);
    } else {
        return '\0';
    }
}

private static int getIndexAt(int x, int y) {
    return 9*x + y;
}

private static Point[] mergeArr(Point[] arr1, Point[] arr2) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < arr1.length && arr1[i] != null) {
        i++;
    }

    while (j < arr2.length && arr2[j] != null) {
        arr1[i + j] = arr2[j];
        j++;
    }

    return arr1;
}

private static String getMove(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return Integer.toString(x1) + " " + Integer.toString(y1) + " " + Integer.toString(x2) + " " + Integer.toString(y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read up on commonly used algorithms like [alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) that help to reduce the search space?

Comment: I just read up on it, but it's not particularly helpful since I'm only getting 5 entire round deep, and as there are 4 players and not 2, I could only start eliminating trees at the 5th level. It did give me an idea for a sub-optimal system that will run quicker though.

Comment: I forgot that it was only for two players but it should be a good starting point to find similar techniques for a more general solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this is quite a bit of code so just some generic remarks and advise for now:

1. Your code is a prime example of what I would call spaghetti code. It's unmaintainable and if you come back to it in 6 months time you'll have a hard time understanding what all of it is doing.
2. Just from skimming over the code there seems to be a lot of code repetition especially in `getBestMove`.
3. Strings in Java are immutable. Which means any operation which modifies a string actually creates a new string. Also you do a lot of parsing and converting back and forth between strings and numbers which won't help with the speed issue.

So my general advise would be: Create a dedicated `Board` class which encapsulates the board access and operations performed on the board. As backing store I'd probably chose a 2d int-array representing the cells. If you need to print it on screen you can have a convenient output method which converts it into the string representation.

This will get rid of a lot of unnecessary converting to and from strings and should result in some speedup (how much exactly I can't say). It will also provide a starting point for a better code structure.

Comment: Yourpoint about spaghetti code makes a lot of sense. I started this code assuming it would be rather simple and didn't pay much attention to structure. Things got out of hand rather quickly though.

Comment: Would an array of bytes produce measurably faster code than an array of int? I've read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst) that in arrays, bytes get packed. This should result in 4 times less memory usage for boards, right? Then again, calculations with bytes seem to be slower than those with ints.

Comment: It might be faster or it might not be. In the end accessing individual bytes requires un-aligned memory access or byte masking and shifting. On the other hand it might benefit from better caching due too smaller size. My guess would be that it won't make a huge difference but you'll have to try to find out